# How does the Perl's Slurp module work?

Tags: perl, slurp

I had a look at the source of [Slurp](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc/Slurp) and I would love to understand how does `slurp()` work:

```
sub slurp { 
    local( $/, @ARGV ) = ( wantarray ? $/ : undef, @_ ); 
    return <ARGV>;
}
```

Where is the file even opened?

Comment: Related http://stackoverflow.com/q/206661/100754 and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2213485/how-do-i-read-a-files-contents-into-a-perl-scalar I don't see any reason to use this module.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

See [`ARGV`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlvar.html#ARGV) and [`$/`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlvar.html#%24/) in [perldoc perlvar](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlvar.html).

See also [Path::Class:File::slurp](https://metacpan.org/pod/Path::Class::File#file-slurp).

Comment: Note that File::Slurp is now considered broken since it doesn't know what to do with encodings, and it's slow. See http://blogs.perl.org/users/leon_timmermans/2013/05/why-you-dont-need-fileslurp.html

Comment: @briandfoy I have grown really fond of [Path::Class](https://metacpan.org/pod/Path::Class) and changed my recommendation to reflect that.

Answer (score 5):

[`ARGV`](http://p3rl.org/var#ARGV) is a handle, the file has been opened implicitly.

Answer (score 1):

This snippet puts the filename in `@ARGV`. The `ARGV` filehandle implicitly opens the files it sees in `@ARGV`. This is the same filehandle that we don't see in the diamond operator `<>` since it's the default filehandle for that operator.

This is the same Perl idiom as:

```
 my $data = do { local( @ARGV, $/ ) = $file; <> };
```