# parsing json file using perl

Tags: json, perl

I am trying to parse a json file in perl. I want to extract the key "name" and corresponding value of it.
my file looks like this

```
{
 "data":[
    {
        "name":"ABC",
        "id":"123",
    },
    {
        "name":"PQR",
        "id":"456",
    },
    {
        "name":"XYZ",
        "id":"789",
    }
]
}
```

I am trying with below code:

```
#/usr/lib/perl
use lib qw( ..);
use LWP::Simple;
use JSON;
my $filename = '/file.txt';
my $data;
if (open (my $json_str, $filename))
{
  local $/ = undef;
  my $json = JSON->new;
  $data = $json->decode(<$json_str>);
  close($json_stream);
}
print $data->{name};
```

But I not getting any output.

Can anyone tel me what is wrong ?

Comment: http://jsonlint.com/  use this page to validate or json

Answer (score 27):

Your json file is invalid.

Lines 5,10,15 should not end with a comma since that is the last key/value pair of those hashes.

After you fix that, here is a version of your code that gives you the expected result:

```
#/usr/lib/perl
use strict;
use warnings;

use lib qw(..);

use JSON qw( );

my $filename = 'file.txt';

my $json_text = do {
   open(my $json_fh, "<:encoding(UTF-8)", $filename)
      or die("Can't open \"$filename\": $!\n");
   local $/;
   <$json_fh>
};

my $json = JSON->new;
my $data = $json->decode($json_text);

for ( @{$data->{data}} ) {
   print $_->{name}."\n";
}
```

Some of the problems:

- You were using `$json_stream` and `$json_str`. You meant to use `$json_stream` in all places to denote the filehandle
- The `$data->{name}` should be applied to all members of the array in the .json file, not to the json itself. So you need to iterate through them first

When debugging this, make sure your json is valid. Either through [jsonlint.com](http://jsonlint.com/) or the [json_xs](http://cpansearch.perl.org/src/MLEHMANN/JSON-XS-2.33/bin/json_xs) utility that comes with [JSON::XS](https://metacpan.org/module/JSON::XS) from cpan.

JSON can describe complicated data structures so when you parse it into Perl you get a complex data structure too. Try to first have a look at the data structure using [Data::Dumper](https://metacpan.org/module/Data::Dumper) or [Data::Printer](https://metacpan.org/module/Data::Printer) or [Data::TreeDumper](https://metacpan.org/module/Data::TreeDumper)

Comment: Doesn't your `do open(...)` leak an opened file?

Comment: The [filehandle is closed](http://stackoverflow.com/a/953885/827519) when it [goes out of scope](http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=287647#287686).

Answer (score 6):

Besides having an extra comma in the JSON string, you do not reference the right values. Always use

```
use strict; 
use warnings;
```

-- they will tell you what's wrong. In this case, you are printing an undefined value `$data->{name}`, a variable that has not been assigned a value. If you print your decoded structure in `Data::Dumper` it looks like this:

```
$VAR1 = {
          'data' => [
                      {
                        'name' => 'ABC',
                        'id' => '123'
                      },
                      {
                        'name' => 'PQR',
                        'id' => '456'
                      },
                      {
                        'name' => 'XYZ',
                        'id' => '789'
                      }
                    ]
        };
```

And as you can see, `$data` is actually a hash reference, where the first and only key is called `'data'`, whose value is an array with three elements, each containing a hash reference. So, in order to print those elements you would do something like:

```
print $data->{data}[0]{name};   # prints ABC

my $aref = $data->{data};
for my $element (@$aref) {
    print $element->{name};     # prints ABC, PQR, XYZ
}
```

Comment: Here's an alternative `map { print $_->{name}; } @{$data->{data}};` .  Or you can `print join(",",(map{ $_->{name}} @{$data->{data}}));`  It's still a loop though. Why is a non-loop solution required ?