# Remove multi-line C style /* comments */ using Perl regex

Tags: regex, perl, comments

How do I remove multi-line C style comments like:

```
/* comments
   comments
   comments
   comments */
```

I am able to remove comments in one line like `/* comments */` by using several codes provided in other questions.

```
s#/\*[\s\S]*?\*/##sg;
s#/\*(.*?)\*/##sg;
s#/\*[^*]*\*+([^/*][^*]*\*+)*/|("(\\.|[^"\\])*"|'(\\.|[^'\\])*'|.[^/"'\\]*)#defined $2 ? $2 : ""#gse
```

All three regexes above do not work with multi-line comments. How can they be handled?

Comment: Do you need to deal with bastardiferous C comments like ``/\`` on one line, ``\`` on the next, and ``* comment *\`` on the next, another line with just ``\``, and finally `/` on the next line, marking the end of comment?  Do you need to allow for any of those backslashes to be written `??/` instead of ``\``?

Comment: I managed to remove one line comments like `// something`. However, I'm not very sure about the backslashes you mentioned, sorry, coding newbie here ;)

Comment: Good.  Does that also handle multi-line ``// something\`` lines with `continuation of previous comment` on the next line?  If you're a newbie at this, you can decide that the bastardiferous comments are out of scope, not least because anyone actually writing them deserves to be hung, drawn, and quartered for abuse of C (or C++, or Java, or whatever language it really is).  Nevertheless, that's the sort of nonsense that compiler writers have to deal with.

Comment: @AvinashRaj: well, for one thing, comments can start at the end of one line and continue onto subsequent lines.  Also, at some point, you have to worry about: `const char c_start[] = "/*"; const char c_end[] = "*/";` which does not contain any comment.  You can even have non-portable code like `int c1 = '/*'; int c2 = '*/';` which also doesn't contain any comments.  Doing this job thoroughly is decidedly non-trivial.  However, this sort of stuff may well be beyond what the OP needs to handle, and he can thank his lucky stars he's not producing a commercial-grade comment remover.

Comment: I see what you meant earlier. I don't need to  handle those comments. My task only contains multi line `/*something*/` and `//something`.

Comment: Tha answer is in the FAQ: http://perldoc.perl.org/perlfaq6.html#How-do-I-use-a-regular-expression-to-strip-C-style-comments-from-a-file?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would do like,

```
perl -0777pe 's/\/\*(?:(?!\*\/).)*\*\/\n?//sg' file
```

Example:

```
$ cat fi
/* comments
   comments
   comments
   comments */
bar
$ perl -0777pe 's/\/\*(?:(?!\*\/).)*\*\/\n?//sg' fi
bar
```

Comment: The one-liner works if I type it in the command window. However, I'm supposed to open a text file and remove comments in it. `s/\/\*(?:(?!\*\/).)*\*\/\n?//sg foreach (@lines)` removes single line comments but not multi-line comments. Any ideas?

Comment: i think foreach loop would fetch only  a single line at a time.

Comment: Why are you using paragraph mode `-00`? Did you mean to use slurp mode `-0777`?

Comment: ya, `00pe` won't work if there is a blank line in-between `/*` and `*/`

Comment: Now i see that where my problems at! Is there any way to check the file line by line while removing comments without using foreach/for?

Comment: just read the entire file into a string and do the replacement on that string. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/953707/in-perl-how-can-i-read-an-entire-file-into-a-string