# Shortest way to read a whole file in Perl with ony core modules

Tags: perl

With my oneliners I often want to fetch a whole file inside a string. With only core modules the only solutions I know considering `$file = 'foo'` are:

```
$str = do {local $/; open $fh, '<', $file; <$fh>};
```

Or

```
$str = qx{cat $file};
```

The second method is shorter to write, easier to understand, but involves a lot more complexity behind the curtain (sys_execve).

Is there any better way or a nice sugar that I don't know?

Comment: See also [how can I read an entire file into a string?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/953707/in-perl-how-can-i-read-an-entire-file-into-a-string) and [What is the best way to slurp a file into a string in Perl?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/206661/what-is-the-best-way-to-slurp-a-file-into-a-string-in-perl).

Comment: The second isn't shorter. It only looks that way because you forgot that you needed error checking. Problems opening a file is the most common error!

Comment: "With my oneliners I often want to fetch a whole file inside a string." `perl -0777 -nwE 'say $_' /path/to/file`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

another way is:

```
my $file_content = do{local(@ARGV,$/)=$filename;<>};
```

> Cool, huh? This works by localizing @ARGV and saving $filename as the
>   first element of @ARGV. The empty diamond operator <> automatically
>   opens a filehandle to the first element of @ARGV, which is the
>   filename. If you need to set a PerlIO layer, the filehandle name is
>   ARGV so you can use binmode to set the layer (before the file is
>   read!):

http://perltricks.com/article/21/2013/4/21/Read-an-entire-file-into-a-string

> Perl 6 (still in alpha version) has a built in function to slurp in files. That is, to read the
>   contents of a whole file into a scalar variable.

```
my $data = slurp $filename;
```

http://perl6maven.com/perl6-files

Comment: Good hack, I like it. Unfortunately it is still very cryptical for newbies. Perl miss a native way to slurp files *i.e.* `$str = slurp($file)`

Comment: "Perl 6 has a built in function to slurp in files. That is, to read the contents of a whole file into a scalar variable." http://perl6maven.com/perl6-files

Comment: Perl 6 is still in alpha version. http://perl6.guide/

Comment: Yes and since 2001... I am afraid Perl will be dead before the first release of Perl 6 :(

Comment: http://hastebin.com/irisonamog.pl modernized it for you.

Answer (score 0):

There is a good module at CPAN to do that: [File::Slurp](https://metacpan.org/pod/File::Slurp), a Simple and Efficient Reading/Writing/Modifying of Complete Files

```
# read in a whole file into a scalar variable ($text)
my $text = read_file( $filename ) ;
```

Comment: Indeed it is good, but not part of core modules. Thus, it is not a very compatible solution :(

Comment: I never understand why people are so against modules in Perl and only want to use the core library. The modules exist to help people and to save people having to write their own implementations of features. You never see many people in other languages like java saying i only want to use the core java library and no others jars.

Comment: not so rarely install a new module requires to local compile it and when you do "make" it fails.

Comment: second if you have a script that do something simple and you have to distribute it, you don' like to have many dependencies.

Comment: File::Slurp is a pure Perl module, so compilation is not required in this case