# How to read STDIN into a variable in perl

Tags: perl, file, stdin

I want to read from STDIN and have everything in a variable, how can I do this?

I'm know know almost nothing about Perl, and needed to create CGI script to read data from POST request, and was not able to find anything how to do that.

Comment: Presuming that you know how to assign to variables and read STDIN, I imagine you're having some other unspecified problem.  Are you trying to read to EOF (list context)? Are you reading from a pipe that does not close?  Are you reading from a Terminal?

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/953707/in-perl-how-can-i-read-an-entire-file-into-a-string

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is probably not the most definitive way:

```
my $stdin = join("", <STDIN>);
```

Or you can enable slurp mode and get the whole file in one go:

```
local $/;
my $stdin = <STDIN>;
```

[but see `man perlvar` for caveats about making global changes to special variables]

If instead of a scalar you want an array with one element per line:

```
my @stdin = <STDIN>;
```

Answer (score 3):

```
my $var = do { local $/; <> };
```

This doesn't quite read Stdin, it also allows files to specify on the command line for processing (like sed or grep).

This does include line feeds.